# YouTube Live Streaming API encryption RTMPS

Tags: encryption, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on a project that requires the use of ssl (or other encryption) of my video stream.

From what I have been able to read I can set the YouTube player to require encryption but what about the upstream?

RTMP works fine but if I try to stream via RTMPS I get:

> RTMP_Connect1, handshake failed.

I haven't been able to find anything about this in the YouTube Live API docs or the YouTube help section.

And, Shouldn't encryption be the default on the web anyway?

Comment: By YouTube player encryption, do you mean setting the video privacy settings to Public, Private, or Unlisted?  That is WAY different and unrelated to RTMP vs RTMPS.  YouTube only supports RTMP and not RTMPS at this time.

Comment: No. The YouTube player works fine and encrypts using https by default and I can even force it to require encryption using the contentDetails.enableContentEncryption 
The problem is the video stream going from my streaming server up to YouTube Live.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the reference doc for the livestream object (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams), you'll see that, currently, the `cdn.ingestionType` parameter only allows the value of rtmp ... logic would dictate, then, that the endpoint can't handle RTMPS.

As to your second question, well, that's well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question! :)

Comment: Do you mean I need to append video stream to cdnSettings.setIngestionType("rtmp");
Please it will be helpful if update it in answer of HOW